# Why doesn't FindClusters find any clusters in this case?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to use FindClusters to segment data points into similar numbers but so far I couldn't get it work for this example:

```
l = {110, 111, 115, 117, 251, 254, 254, 259, 399, 400, 401, 
     402, 542, 546, 549, 554, 660, 660, 660, 660};
FindClusters[l]
(*
-> {{110, 111, 115, 117, 251, 254, 254, 259, 399, 400, 401, 402, 542, 
   546, 549, 554, 660, 660, 660, 660}}
*)
```

If I set the N parameter (to specify: Exactly N clusters), it works:

```
FindClusters[l, 5]
(*
-> {{110, 111, 115, 117}, {251, 254, 254, 259}, 
    {399, 400, 401, 402}, {542, 546, 549, 554}, {660, 660, 660, 660}}
*)
```

However, my intent was to use FindClusters to figure out N.

Comment: You've tried playing around with various `DistanceFunction` settings? `DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance` and `DistanceFunction -> CanberraDistance` work here, for instance...

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, posted an answer simultaneously

Comment: @bel, no prob, though I have a feeling we got lucky, and these only work for the particular case that OP presented, since OP says nothing more about the nature of the actual data...

Comment: @J.M. added a "testing framework" (so to speak)

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  I am still trying to figure out why EuclideanDistance doesn't work in this case.  @J.M.: context is a an OCR algorithm I am trying to implement.  I am trying to normalize a grid that has been estimated by WatershedComponents (See my other [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/implementing-ocr-without-using-textrecognize)) .  It's probably too complex to include here.

Comment: @SvenK Image processing in Mma is quite powerful. Perhaps you don't need to use `FindClusters[]`. Mind to share more details?

Comment: @belisarius AFAIU the problem is that WatershedComponents/ImageTake don't really allow accessing the "bitmap" of a component, so I am using "BoundingBox" but the box is including parts of other characters, so I wanted to smooth the boundingboxes before calling ImageTake.  Code example:

    i = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta5wf.png"]  
    ws = WatershedComponents[i];  
    ColorCombine[{Image[mc, "Bit"], i, i}]  
    ImageTake[i, Sequence @@ Reverse@Transpose@Last[#]] & /@ 
 ComponentMeasurements[ws, "BoundingBox"]

Comment: Sorry, it seems the code formatting described in the help for comment formatting doesn't work.

Comment: @belisarius I created a gist for the example: https://gist.github.com/3965569

Comment: @SvenK Try `mc = MorphologicalComponents@ColorNegate@i;
p = Position[mc, #] & /@ Range@Max@mc; ColorNegate /@ 
 Image /@ (SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ 
       Transpose[# - Min@# + 1 & /@ Transpose@#]] & /@ p)`

Comment: @SvenK Do you have measure for the degree of fit for the number of clusters found ?

Comment: @image_doctor No, there seems to be no indication as to how well the data could be fitted into clusters, which seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Bray-Curtis distance `Total[Abs[u-v]]/Total[Abs[u+v]]`:

```
FindClusters[{110, 111, 115, 117, 251, 254, 254, 259, 399, 400, 401, 
              402, 542, 546, 549, 554, 660, 660, 660, 660}, 
              DistanceFunction -> BrayCurtisDistance]
(*
{{110, 111, 115, 117}, 
 {251, 254, 254, 259}, 
 {399, 400, 401, 402},
 {542, 546, 549, 554}, 
 {660, 660, 660, 660}}
*)
```

Edit:

Here you have an experimental setup to test the `FindClusters[]` options in problems like yours:

```
l1 = RandomInteger[{100, 1000}, 10];
l2 = Join @@ (IntegerPart /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 10], 10] & /@ l1);
l3 = FindClusters[l2, DistanceFunction -> CanberraDistance];
Framed@Show[MapIndexed[
            Graphics[{ColorData[3][#2[[1]]],
                     Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}] & /@ #1}] &, l3], 
            PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Neat addition. :) OP should now be able to play around with the `Method` and `DistanceFunction` options easily, to see what suits his data best.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure why the default option for `FindClusters` with  `EuclideanDistance` and `Method->"Optimize"` fails to distinguish any clusters.

Here are some results which might add a little detail:

Here are the numeric distance functions:

```
dfs = {EuclideanDistance, SquaredEuclideanDistance, NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance, 
ManhattanDistance, ChessboardDistance, BrayCurtisDistance, CanberraDistance, 
CosineDistance, CorrelationDistance}
```

Applying the various distance functions and methods:

```
Length@FindClusters[l, DistanceFunction -> #, Method -> "Agglomerate"] & /@ dfs
Length@FindClusters[l, DistanceFunction -> #, Method -> "Optimize"] & /@ dfs
```

> {5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1}
>    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1}

And in tabular form:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it is possible to use the `EuclideanDistance` function for this data, but only with agglomerative clustering.