# Accessing the graph Thinning produces without losing all the edges' lengths/slopes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, ocr

[image: overview]

This is a follow up to the [OCR question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/implementing-ocr-without-using-textrecognize) I had earlier.

What I want to do is to use Thinning to create "skeletons" of images of characters and then compare their shapes, utilizing such properties as the slopes/lengths of the edges.  The problem is however that I have not been able so far to access the graph Thinning produces. MorphologicalGraph is what I have found in the documentation but this removes a lot of information.  And for comparing graphs so far I only have found IsomorphicGraphQ which doesn't seem to offer much customization (tolerances for matching).

The code below demonstrates the problem I have with my current approach.  Because MorphologicalGraph reduces the Thinned images to a very similar shape for all these characters, the code will deem a "C" character similar to "I" and "S":

```
Graphize[u_] := MorphologicalGraph@Thinning@ColorNegate[Import[u]]
whichQ = Graphize["http://i.imgur.com/2Fxyh.gif"] (* C *)
i = Graphize["http://i.imgur.com/SPp7R.gif"]  (* I *)
c = Graphize["http://i.imgur.com/SeXA7.gif"]  (* C *)
s = Graphize["http://i.imgur.com/aguQ6.gif"]  (* S *)
IsomorphicGraphQ[whichQ, i] (* -> True *)
IsomorphicGraphQ[whichQ, c] (* -> True *)
IsomorphicGraphQ[whichQ, s] (* -> True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic problem is that the letters I, C and S have the same graph - they all consist of two endpoints (vertices) with a single line (edge) going from one to the other. The *shape* of the line doesn't change the graph. The only other thing `MorphologicalGraph` gives you is that the `EdgeWeights` of the resulting graph correspond to the number of pixels in the skeleton between the two vertices.

One idea that I had is to try and increase the complexity of the graphs by mirroring each letter vertically and horizontally. I also found it helped to remove very short (low weight) edges.

Here are the functions to do the mirroring and pruning:

```
mirror[letter_] := Module[{im},
  im = ImagePad[ImageCrop[ColorNegate@Rasterize[letter]], -2];
  ImageAssemble[{{ImageReflect[im, Left], im}, 
   {ImageReflect[ImageReflect[im, Left]], ImageReflect[im]}}]];

prune[g_] := Module[{ew, el},
  ew = PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight];
  el = EdgeList[g];
  el = Sort /@ (el /. (Pick[el, ew, w_ /; w < 10] /. UndirectedEdge -> Rule));
  Graph[DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[el], UndirectedEdge[x_, x_]]]];
```

Create a reference set from the letters A-Z in "Arial" font:

```
chars = FromCharacterCode /@ Range[65, 90];
reference = Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial", 100] & /@ chars;
refgraphs = prune[MorphologicalGraph[mirror[#]]] & /@ reference;
```

Here are the mirrored letter images and the corresponding graphs:

```
Grid[Partition[ImageResize[mirror[#], {Automatic, 50}] & /@ reference,  5]]
Grid[Partition[Show[#, ImageSize -> {50, 50}] & /@ refgraphs, 5]]
```

[image]
[image]

Now create a test set using a different font ("Calibri")

```
test = Style[#, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 100] & /@ chars;
testgraphs = prune[MorphologicalGraph[mirror[#]]] & /@ test;
```

Check the isomorphism:

```
Outer[IsomorphicGraphQ, testgraphs, refgraphs] // Boole // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

Even with such similar fonts as Arial and Calibri, it doesn't work perfectly, though the mirroring has certainly helped. Perhaps you can think of a better way to create unique graphs from the letters.

Comment: To the point of the general approach, I would probably use the graph approach as one factor. For example, `H` and `I` share a graph (assuming H doesn't have serifs). If a symbol falls in the `H/I` category, then other methods can be used to further discriminate between those symbols.

Comment: @amr I tried to use CornerFilter/EdgeDetect as an additional measure but it wasn't really working.  HammingDistance might be a good additional measure to use but it needs a full graph  representation (which one can't create from a picture with standard MMA functions as it seems).  edit: Maybe unthinned image->MorphologicalGraph->HammingDistance is an idea for an additional measurement

Comment: @Simon-Woods Thanks for the answer.  Interesting idea.

Comment: @SvenK, it's an interesting problem. I wonder if the `EdgeWeights` (i.e. skeleton length in pixels) could be compared to the Euclidean distance between two vertices, to estimate how straight or curvy the line is.