# Blank output from TextRecognize

Tags: ocr

Why am I getting blank output from `TextRecognize` for the following image?
Is it because of the size of the image?

Neither am I getting output for this code:

```
x = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqrD.jpg"];
TextRecognize[x]
```

nor for this one:

```
x = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqrD.jpg"];
img = ImagePartition[x, {50, 69}];
MatrixForm[img];
p=img[[4,1]];
TextRecognize[p]
```

[image]

Comment: The way `TextRecognize` works is that it looks for groups of letters and guesses what the word is. So it's better for complete sentences, it's not good for individual letters. In this image especially the letters have a spatial arrangement `TextRecognize` cannot make sense of, so you are better off using `ImageCorrelate` and some sample letters (there are other Q&As about this).

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/implementing-ocr-without-using-textrecognize) is what you need.

Comment: @Pickett This was also my first thought, but please see the section recognizing random characters from my answer. It's far from a complete answer though.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I've seen `TextRecognize` being used like this before, for example [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/can-textrecognize-read-digits), but it's just not very good at it. For varying spatial distributions it is a much safer bet to use image correlation.

Comment: If talking about spatial distribution then my second code should work properly in there this whole image is partitioned in 228 images of size 50x69 even there its not working

Comment: Abdullah, in your second code you only call `TextRecognise` on one element of that matrix. You cannot expect that it somehow knows it is part of a matrix. Also the given partition does not tell you much about where the characters are, as well as that such behaviour of `TextRecognise` (to work with matrices) is simply not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to recognise a single character in isolation. Even when I make it easier

```
y1 = ImageCrop[
   ImageCrop[img1, {100, 225}, {Left, Bottom}], {20, 25}, {Left, Top}];
y2 = ImageResize[y1, Scaled[10]];
y3 = Sharpen[y2];
y4 = Binarize[y3]
```

[image]

We still have that

```
TextRecognize@y4
```

gives `""` . But there is hope, see the next section.

**Recognizing multiple random characters**

`TextRecognize` can find characters that do not make up words (I'm not sure if sentences matter here). A key element here is that the characters are regularly spaced. Let's get an example from the docs

```
wolframImg =
 ImageCrop[
  ImageCrop[
   ImageResize[
    Import[
     "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/TextRecognize.\
en/I_20.gif"]
    ,
    Scaled[5]
    ]
   ,
   {434, 240}
   ,
   {Left, Bottom}
   ]
  ,
  {408, Full}
  ,
  {Right, Top}
  ]
```

![enter image description here][2]

`TextRecognize` works reasonably well on this, as advertised.

```
TextRecognize[wolframImg]
```

> ```
> ZSI-IC  
> HSKRN  
> CHKRVD
> ```

`TextRecognize` actually often gives quite a few false positives, when it is confident about a lot of (other) characters. This gave me the (silly) idea to compose this image with characters from your example.

```
y4Copies = Table[y4, {2}, {5}];
y5 = ImageAssemble[y4Copies];
y6 = ImageResize[y5, First@ImageDimensions@wolframImg];
compoImg = ImageAssemble[{{y6}, {wolframImg}}]
```

[image]

Now we can do

```
TextRecognize[compoImg]
```

which gives

> ```
> EEEEE  
> EEEEE  
> ZSHC  
> HSKRN  
> CHKRVD
> ```

Comment: Yes Recognizes it successfully but tesseract in mathematica does not recognize single character it requires a whole word be it a random or logical..Still on my way to make it recognize single character

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter implementation of the [idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52344/280) of [Jacob Akkerboom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4330/jacob-akkerboom) to assemble the characters in a line:

```
$Version
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbqrD.jpg"];
c = ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@Binarize@i, "Image", #"ConvexCoverage" < .9 &];
row = ImageAssemble[{ImagePad[ImageResize[#, {Automatic, 200}], 10] & /@ c[[;; , 2]]}]
TextRecognize[row]
```

> ```
> "11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> "ESEEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAHHHHA"
> ```

The parameters `200` and `10` were carefully chosen by trial and error for achieving best possible recognition quality. And the latter is still leaves much to be desired. :(

Such poor quality of `TextRecognize` is especially surprising considering that Tesseract (which `TextRecognize` uses under the hood) shows excellent quality and does not require any assistance at all, as it can be checked for example using its Windows GUI [gImageReader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimagereader/).

Comment: Actually I have given a report last time,but don't get any response till now.

Comment: @yode Please inform us if you receive an answer from the tech support. I was playing with the image from this question in the hope that improvements of `TextRecognize` in version 11.1 make recognition of individual characters straightforward. But I see that it is not the case: `RecognitionPrior -> "Character"` improves nothing as well as the other option choices! It is a shame that WRI can't properly integrate Tesseract into *Mathematica*...